# Can namerefs (declare -n) be used with arrays in bash? What does the documentation mean when it says declare -n cannot be applied to arrays?

Tags: bash

In another question to stackoverflow, I asked how to pass array to a function. An answer recommended me a previous answers. 
  One answer suggests that declare with -n option, referencing, is useful to pass array to an function, like following,

```
declare -a array=( 1 2 )

function array_pass_by_reference_func() {
  local -n aug=${1:-dummy}
  echo "pass by reference : array[0] = ${aug[0]}"
  echo "pass by reference : array[1] = ${aug[1]}"
  echo "pass by reference : array = ${aug[@]}"
}

# execute an example function above
array_pass_by_reference_func "array"

# output
pass by reference : array[0] = 1
pass by reference : array[1] = 2
pass by reference : array = 1 2
```

It looks working well.
My question here is about an instruction of declare -n in bash manual,

```
The -n attribute cannot be applied to array variables.
```

I would like to confirm that can I pass array to a function with declare -n option?
My original question is marked as duplicated and the previous question is too old to ask this question. So please let me ask it here.
Thank you very much.

Comment: As an aside, consider making a habit of avoiding the `function` keyword -- just defining your function as `array_pass_by_reference_func() {`, with no `function` before it, avoids making your code needlessly incompatible with baseline POSIX. (Granted, you've got other *needful* incompatibilities in your code, but better to have incompatibilities only by intent rather than by habit).

Comment: @Charles Duffy : thank you for telling me the manner. I did not know the function keyword is out of POSIX.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Further down on the `man` page, under the `PARAMETERS` heading, it also says:

> However, nameref variables can reference array variables and  subscripted  array  variables.

In other words:

- You can't declare a nameref variable *itself* as an array (`declare -a -n foo=...` will result in a syntax error).
- But a nameref variable can *reference* an array.

Therefore, your approach should be safe.

Comment: thank you for answering. I quoted a part of item about declare command. I suppose you tells me the right place  to read, PARAMETERS. Thank you very much.

Comment: @mora: Glad to hear it helped; good point re location of the quote: didn't realize it was a different section - answer updated.