# How do format and traverse an array that contains arrays ,and each array contains an array?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to create multidimensional within arrays that are contained in an array.

```
tests=("'0' '1 2'" "'4' '5 6'")
```

in each array within tests, I want to have sub arrays. With the first array "'0' '1,2'", make another for loop to go through the contents of the sub array.

Comment: Why are you trying to force bash to do this? bash only has one-dimensional arrays. Pick the right tool for the job.

Comment: Related on unix.SE: [How can I create a multidimensional array, or something similar, with bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/741723) - as multiple people said there, if you want this, you're better off with a programming language other than the shell, such as perl or python which can still do shell-like things like easily run other programs and capture their outputs, but also have real data structures allowing arbitrary nesting of dictionaries (hashes) and lists (arrays).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since bash 4.3. (3 levels, the first contains only one element for the demo):

```
arr01=(0 '1 2')
arr02=(4 '5 6')
arr1=(arr01 arr02)
arr=(arr1)

declare -n elmv1 elmv2

for elmv1 in "${arr[@]}"; do
    for elmv2 in "${elmv1[@]}"; do
        for elm in "${elmv2[@]}"; do
            echo "<$elm>"
        done
    done
done
```

Before 4.3

```
arr01=(0 '1 2')
arr02=(4 '5 6')
arr1=('arr01[@]' 'arr02[@]')
arr=('arr1[@]')

for elmv1 in "${arr[@]}"; do
    for elmv2 in "${!elmv1}"; do
        for elm in "${!elmv2}"; do
            echo "<$elm>"
        done
    done
done
```

Comment: What's the point of the line `declare -n elmv1 elmv2`?

Comment: @clime, if you have bash 4.3 or later, type `man bash` and search for `declare -n`.

Comment: @linux_sa Sorry, still unclear. My bash 4.3.48 man says:`...running declare -n ref=$1 inside  the  function  creates ...`, but the answer here states `declare -n elmv1 elmv2` without the `=`. Is that the same? Quite unclear to me.
And  `help declare` isn't much help either:
`-n make NAME a reference to the variable named by its value`. That is pretty much meaningless to me.

Comment: @kebs `/declare` below `/^SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS`

Comment: @kebs it similar to a parameter indirection, it allow to read or write to an indirect variable, safer than using  `eval`

Comment: `man bash - declare: -n     Give  each  name the nameref attribute, making it a name reference to another variable.  That other variable is defined by the value of name.  All references, assignments,  and  attribute modifications  to name, except those using or changing the -n attribute itself, are performed on the variable referenced by name's value.  The nameref attribute cannot be applied to array variables.` -- But `elmv1 and v2` are arrays?

Comment: @Timo, [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40593912/1454708) seems to explain this last sentence.

Comment: `a=( 1 2 ); declare -n a=b;` --> `bash: declare: a: reference variable cannot be an array`
otherwise
`declare -n b=a; b=(3 4); declare -p a b`

Comment: Another issue, why is it not possible `arr1=((0 '1 2') (3 4))` - `syntax error near unexpected token ('`

Comment: indeed arrays can't be nested in the answer the name is used as reference, elmv1 is really "arr1"