# Dynamic array name in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, variable-names

Because bash doesn't support "arrays in arrays",
I'm trying to dynamize variable name when calling arrays.

bash version : 4.2

I used this expansion method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18124325/9336478

```
#!/bin/bash
# data are pre-defined and type is determined later

declare -a data_male
declare -a data_female

data_male=(value1 value2)
data_female=(value3 value4)

type="male" 

for value in ${${!data_$type}[@]};do
  echo $value
done
```

and it did not work

`line 20: ${${!data_$type}[@]} : bad substitution`

How do I sort this out?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44831174/10971581

Comment: Which version of Bash are you using?

Comment: @vdavid I'm currently using 4.2 edited the post

Comment: You can't nest expansions in a single step like that, you need to set a variable to what you want expanded (and that'd include things like `[@]` to get all elements of an array). Something like `data_type_contents="data_${type}[@]"; for value in ${!data_type_contents}; do ...`

Comment: do you have the option of installing a newer version of `bash`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, in Bash 4.2 you need to `eval` the array.

```sh
printf -v evaluator 'for value in ${%s[@]};do\n  echo $value\ndone' "data_$type"
eval "$evaluator"
```

`printf` will inject the name of the array designated by `data_$type` into the `%s` part, and then the result of the string is assigned to the variable `evaluator`.

So, the first part builds a string designed to be evaluated, and then you evaluate it.

Instead of newline characters `\n` you can also use *actual* newlines:

```sh
printf -v evaluator 'for value in ${%s[@]};do
  echo $value
done' "data_$type"
eval "$evaluator"
```

You should make sure that the contents of your arrays are safe because this can be used to inject malicious code.

Answer (score 3):

If OP can get a newer version of `bash` installed then a nameref (name reference, available in bash 4.3+) could be used:

```
declare -a data_male
declare -a data_female

data_male=(value1 value2)
data_female=(value3 value4)

type="male"

declare -n arr="data_${type}"       # dynamically declare arr[] as a name ref to data_male[]

for ndx in "${!arr[@]}"
do
    echo "${arr[${ndx}]}"
done
```

This generates:

```
value1
value2
```